# Why is a C++ class's destructor called after assigning using a converting constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

Given this class:

```
class Baz
{
public:
    Baz() : Baz(0) {}
    Baz(int i) { _i = i; }
    Baz(Baz const &b) { _i = b._i * 10; }
    ~Baz() { }
private:
    int _i;
};
```

If I debug and step through this code:

```
Baz a = 4;
```

The `Baz` constructor that takes an `int` is called, as expected, and I get a `Baz` with `_i` of 4. That's good.

But if I do this:

```
Baz b;
b = 4;
```

The first line calls the default constructor, as expected. The second line calls the `int` constructor *and then the destructor*.

My first expectation was that the second line of the second example would simply call the `int` constructor in assigning to `b`. I didn't expect the destructor to be called, but if it's first converting the integer `4` to a `Baz` before assignment, it would make sense to destroy it afterward. But then I'd expect the copy constructor to be called when assigning that temporary value to `b`. The `Baz` that is destroyed has the value `4` for `_i`, so it's not the object created on the first line.

What's going on here exactly? Why the difference between these two scenarios?

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with the assignment operator. I recommend reading about the Rule of Three (or Rule of Five), which helps a lot here. Links: [Rule of Three on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), [Rule of Three on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
b = 4;
```

first calls the `int` constructor of `Baz`, to construct a temporary `Baz` with the value 4. This temporary is destroyed at the semi-colon.

The assignment does not call the copy-constructor, but actually calls the copy-assignment operator, which has the signature `Baz& operator=(Baz const &);`.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
Baz a = 4;
```

Is equivelent to:

```
Baz a(4);   // It simply constructs the object.
            // Note the `=` is not an assignment when
            // used in a declaration like this. It is
            // simply short hand (syntactic sugar) for
            // a single argument constructor.
```

While these two lines:

```
Baz b;      // Default construct thus setting _i to zero.
b = 4;      // This **IS** an assignment and needs an assignment
            // operator (or there is a compiler error).

            // Note there is no assignment operator that takes
            //      an integer. But there is a default assignment
            //      operator that takes a Baz by const reference.
            //
            //      This is auto generated by the compiler.
            //      See rule of 5
            //         Baz& operator=(Baz const& copy): _i(copy._i){return *this)
            //
            // So the compiler must convert the integer to Baz before 
            // an assignment is allowed. The compiler is allowed to 
            // create an Object using a one parameter constructor so
            // that line is equivalent too:

  // Equiv
  b = Baz(4);  // So this creates a temporary Baz object here.
               // Then the assignment operator is called.
               // Then at the end of the statement the temporary
               // object must be destroyed so we call the destructor  
               // on the temporary.
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `Baz a = 4;` is just syntax sugar for `Baz a(4);`, so it is calling the `Baz(int)` converting constructor directly.

`Baz` does not have an `operator=(int)` defined, but it has an `operator=(const Baz&)` instead (which is being generated by the compiler in your example).  And `Baz` has a `Baz(int)` constructor.  And a `const Baz&` parameter can bind to an rvalue, and there is only 1 implict conversion from an `int` to a `Baz`.  So, the compiler is able to treat the statement `b = 4;` as `b = Baz(4);`, ie it creates a temporary `Baz` object and passes it to `operator=`.  The temporary is destroyed at the end of the statement that creates it (ie, at the `;`).

So, it is the `int` constructor and destructor of that temporary `Baz` object that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can only be used to create a new object.

`b = 4;` doesn't create `b`, so it can't call a constructor on `b`. Instead it creates a temporary `Baz` instance using the `Baz(int i)` constructor, and then assigns the temporary to `b` (using `operator=`, which is generated by the compiler in your case).

The temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression (i.e. when control reaches `;`), that's why you see a destructor call.